# 2D Arrays in Java Program

Tags: java, arrays, string, multidimensional-array

My program is supposed to gets a phrase from the user then returns to the user an encrypted code of their choice (either ROT13 or ATBASH) of the phrase they entered. My code compiles and everything and lets the user input the required stuff but when they enter the phrase to be encrypted, nothing happens.. like the new encrypted code doesnt show up, and i dont know what wrong with it!
Please help! Thank you!

```
   import java.io.*;

public class J4_1_EncryptionVer4
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));//BufferedReader reads user input

    //String array letterA[] is initialized
    String [][] letterA = new String [][]{
    {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"},
    {"N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"},
    {"Z","Y","X","W","V","U","T","S","R","Q","P","O","N","M","L","K","J","I","H","G","F","E","D","C","B","A"},
    };

    System.out.println ("Enter '1' for ROT13 or '2' for ATBASH");//asks user to choose method
    String numA = myInput.readLine();//reads user input and assigns it to string
    int num = Integer.parseInt (numA);//converts string to integer
    int a = 0;//int a is declared

    if (num == 1){//if user enters 1
          a = 1;//set a to 1
    }
    if (num == 2) {//end if//if user enters 2
          a = 2;//set a to 2
        }//end if
    System.out.println ( a);
    System.out.println(num);

    System.out.println ("Please enter a phrase: ");//asks user to enter phrase
    String message = myInput.readLine();//reads user input and assigns it to string

    int x = 0; //declares int var x

    System.out.println ("Your Encrypted code is: ");//prints out scentence


    while (x < message.length())//while loop will run while x is less that the phrase length          
    {
      String text = message.toUpperCase();//converts user input to upper case
      String letter = Character.toString(text.charAt(x));//extracts character from string and assigns it to another string letter

      x++;//increments x by 1 each time

      for(int i=0; i<letterA.length; i++)//for loop declares int i = 0, will run while i is less than the the length of the array letterA, and i will increment by 1 each time
      {
        if(letter.equals(letterA[a][i]))//if the letter is equal to letterA[i]
        {
          System.out.print (letterA[a][i]);//print out the corresponding letter

          break;//breaks from loop

        }//end if

        else if (letter.equals(" "))//else id the letter is equal to a space
        {
          System.out.print(" ");//prints out space
          break;//breaks from loop
        }//end else if        
      }//end for loop
    }//end while loop
  }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: I strongly recommend learning to use a debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because `letterA.length` is 3, so your `for` loop only runs through 3 iterations, instead of 26.

Comment: As opposed to letterA[0].length, letterA[1].length and letterA[2].length all of which *are* 26

Comment: hi! thanks for the answer... but im kind of confused of by what you mean

Comment: @Maddie LetterA is a 2 dimensional array, you've got A-Z in letterA[0] N-M  in letterA[1] and Z-A in letterA[2]. So the length of letterA is 3 but in your code I think you expect it to be 26, which is the length of the **second dimension arrays**

Comment: Your for loop will iterate 3 times - once with `i = 0`, once with `i = 1` and once with `i = 2`.  So depending on the value of `a`, you'll only compare `letter` against A, B and C; or against N, O and P; or against Z, Y and X. Nothing will happen for other letters.

Comment: @DavidWallace so is my goal to get the loop to run for the length of the phrase that is entered `message.length()`?

Comment: Haha, only YOU know what your goal is!  But the way the code could work is to check one letter against every entry in `letterA[0]` - and there are 26 of those.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change your for loop to

```
    for (int i= 0; i < letterA[0].length ; i++ ) {
           if (letter.equals(letterA[0][i]) {
               System.out.print(letterA[a][i]);
               break;              
           }
           else {
                // .........,.......
           }
    }
```

First use the first array as basis.  Compare the letters then if they are equal then get the index of that letter to be used in encrypting

I'm using a bloody phone ryt now so I didn't really compile your code